# How to Auto Refresh <mx:List

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to use event timer every 3 seconds to refresh List. I have created event timer but don't know about function to refresh List.
has anyone ever did this?

I'll appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Refresh list — what exactly do you mean? Border color of the list? :) And why you're using timer? Maybe it is better to describe your problem but not the solution with timer? :)

Comment: haha, It's funny.
I want to show status user in <mx:List. So, I want this component to automatically refresh every 3 seconds to show new data. I thinks timer event more simple than data event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the List to a datasource (arrayCollection). Whenever the arrayCollection being updated, it will refresh the list automatically, example

```
<mx:List dataProvider="{myAC}"/>
```

where myAC is arrayCollection that can be changed to another arrayCollection.

[Code samples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_4.html), check on this line ( "section Binding to arrays" )

Take note that it's better to bind instead of doing something like

```
list.datasource = anotherArrayCollection;
```

Comment: I have did something like this :
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000);
   
   private function startTimer():void{
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandler);
    timer.start();
   }
   
   private function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
    
   }
I think, what will i did in timerhandler to refresh list.
I fill with lstUser.invalidateDisplayList(); but didn't work

Comment: Can post your code here? Should be able to work. Also try to do list.invalidateProperties() after you make change.

Comment: `private var timer:Timer = new Timer(3000); 
private function startTimer():void{ timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandler); timer.start(); 
} 
private function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{ 
} 
I think, what will i did in timerhandler to refresh list. I fill with lstUser.invalidateDisplayList();`